# Run Sinatra on Windows Server 2008

Tags: ruby, sinatra, windows-server-2008, webrick

I'd like to have a simple API running on a webserver (Windows Server 2008).
I've chosen Sinatra with its default Webrick backend.

What I'm not sure how to do is make my sinatra app visible to the outside world? I have remote desktop access to my server, I have the Sinatra app running, but I'm sure it's not configured correctly for response to outside requests.

I'd love any pointers in getting this going.

Comment: Webrick isn't really considered production ready, so in the longer run you may want to consider switching to something else. Thin is a good start http://www.psteiner.com/2012/04/how-to-replace-webrick-with-thin-for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out.

Was pretty much as simple as ensuring sinatra was running with no ip (either run with -e production or use the -o 0.0.0.0 flag), and then most importantly, ensure the port the webrick server was running on was open on the windows server machine. Once the port was open, accessing it via ip:port works.